# Regular expression to match 3 characters before match

Tags: regex

I have a file with lines like

> text text text 3424 text text 3423 **50 US** text 342 text

What I want to match is **`50 US`** (yes, dollars) and ultimately extract that number.
Everything else changes in different lines, there may be more text or less surrounding, but in each line there is only one "US" anchor that I can match.

So what I want to do is to find a way to match **`US`** and get the preceding 3 or 4 characters.

Any ideas? Preferably with sed/awk, but any solution will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl regexes (or anything that understands non-greedy `.*?` expressions) are easier than sed for this:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?(\d+\.?\d*)\s*US.*$/$1/'
```

That will handle things like "11.23" as well.

Comment: I was just about to post my own solution, an ugly thing like `grep -o "[[:digit:]]\{1,3\} US" file |cut -d" " -f 1`, but yours is obviously better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+ US
```

This should work given that US is present only once in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\d+(?= US)
```

This regex will only capture the numeric amount.  The `(?= US)` tells it to match on "US" but not capture it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could use in VBA regex flavor, which also supports lookaheads:

```
" ((.+)(?= US))"
```

- Starts with a space
- Next is the capture group. (.+) I use that instead of \d so that stuff like 5,000 and 11.3 works. In fact, anything works, so if you want the word/number that precedes "US" then this is the way to write it.
- Next is the lookahead. So you only want the capture group that is immediately followed by " US". If it finds it, it will only give you back the capture group, not the lookahead value.